# How to use another Github Pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I have one GH-Page, in my directory name in github. Ok, it's going well, but, i want to create another folder inside this repository for create another Gh-Page.

Are possible?

My Gh-Page: http://reidark.github.io/

My folder what i tried to convert in Gh-Page: http://reidark.github.io/blog

---

Ok, now this works, but the post generated by Jekyll don't work

:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using two separate repositories.

### The User or Organization Pages site

The first repository will be your main site (which it sounds like you already have). It needs to be a [User or Organization site](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#user--organization-pages) and as such must be called `<username>.github.io`, where `<username>` is your GitHub user name, in your case `reidark.github.io`.

Put your content into the `master` branch of this repository.

This site will be available at http://reidark.github.io/.

## The Project Pages site

Your second repository will be your blog, and if you want it can be styled to match your main site so it feels like part of it. It needs to be a [Project site](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#project-pages), and in order to get it to show up at http://reidark.github.io/blog/, the repository should be called `blog`.

Put your content into the special `gh-pages` branch in your `blog` repository, and you should be in business. Your blog site will be available at http://reidark.github.io/blog/.

Comment: Oh, really thank for the explanation. But, the problem is: How i "create" this gh-pages branch. I don't found this in anywhere.

Comment: @user3513330, are you actually *trying to* run this site as separate repositories for a reason? Or do you simply want a few different pages within one site?

Comment: I want to create various pages (blogs with jekyll), and is necessary to do this with various repos. 
But, nevermind, it's done :D Thank you